# MySQL UTF8 for Chrome, UTF8 for IE, but HEADER UTF8 for Chrome and UTF-8 for IE?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, mysqli

With this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

IE displays properly
Chrome displays properly

With this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
```

(without the - between f and 8)

IE displays èéàä etc. with Ã¨$ etc.
Chrome displays properly

Then I have a SQL Connection (database setted with utf8_unicode_ci or ascii_general_ci)

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8')
```

IE and Chrome display èéàäö properly when posting the results

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf-8')
```

IE and Chrome display Ã¨$ etc. or ????? when posting the results

How about the other browsers?
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Content-Type` meta tag, the valid way is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The reason Chrome displays properly is because it is more accepting of errors in this case whereas IE requires it to be written properly.

However it's different with MySQL. They decided to go with the short names. Here is a [list of supported character sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html). This is something done server-side, so it won't matter what browser you are using.

You can also execute the following query:

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET LIKE 'utf%'
```

**Edit:**

Make sure that you are using the same character set to `INSERT` into your database or this could cause undesired effects when you go to view it again.

Comment: Thank you! Now... on the SQL if I set UTF8 IE and Firefox display false, and Chrome properly.
Always on the SQL if I set UTF-8 all browsers display properly, EXCEPT the ' and " they are posted as ??. How can I prevent that? Thank you!

Comment: If you are using PHP, it might be sending a `Content-Type` header. Some browsers prefer this over meta tags. Or you might have manually set the encoding when you were playing around with things. Check out http://web-sniffer.net/ to view the headers sent by the page or use something like the web developer add-on for Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: On the database if I have:
Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã¨Ã©Ã
and decode with mysqli_set_charset('UTF-8') I get èéàè properly
if I decode with mysqli_set_charset('UTF8') I get Ã©Ã¨Ã

On the other hand, if I have on the Database:
èéàéèà
and decode with 'UTF8' I get Ã©Ã¨Ã
if I decode with 'UTF-8' I get èéàè

This makes no sense to me...?

Comment: I solved: when I was posting with a form somenthing on the database I didn't set before the query INSERT the charset and all was INSERTED false. Then it was encoded on posting.
Otherwise the text already properly written on the database was re-encoded (deencoded) and returns as NON UTC8. Is this a possible solution?

Comment: You beat me to it. I was just going to say that you need to make sure you are inserting with the same character set.