# Why does Header Content-Type for POST request differ between chrome and firefox only in by "UTF-8" vs "utf-8"?

Tags: html, angularjs, post, encoding, flask

I am using Flask and Angular JS to process POST request and I am wondering why the Chrome request header has

`application/json;charset=UTF-8`

compared to FireFox

`application/json;charset=utf-8`.

Note the difference is only the chrome capitalizes UTF while FireFox doesnt (utf).

This is probably related to SO: [MySQL UTF8 for Chrome, UTF8 for IE, but HEADER UTF8 for Chrome and UTF-8 for IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742000/mysql-utf8-for-chrome-utf8-for-ie-but-header-utf8-for-chrome-and-utf-8-for-ie) but I wasn't able to understand completely.  I am not using any meta tag in the html, maybe that is the problem?

The reason this is an issue for me is because I had some server side code like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.headers['Content-Type'])
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] in ['application/json;charset=UTF-8']:
```

Which only worked for Chrome and not FireFox until I discovered the capitalization issue with `UTF` vs `utf`.

Comment: They are the same - only written out differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either force both sides to uppercase or lowercase to guarantee a match no matter which browser sends it in.

Not sure which function it is so you may have to look it up, but this is good enough to make my point.

```
if lowercase(request.headers['Content-Type']) in ['application/json;charset=utf-8']:
```

Comment: Thanks.  I already corrected the server side code but it was a nasty bug and I am trying to learn more about why such a subtle difference would exists between browsers...

Comment: Unfortunately that will not be the last time you experience such a thing. Browsers dont care to work under the same rules when they dont have to. IE is the worst and this very thing is why web developers have such a distaste for it